# How to trigger "Leave Site?" message for single page – Turbo & Stimulus JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, stimulusjs, turbo

I want to trigger the in-browser message of "Leave Site?" before leaving a specific form on my site (exactly how StackOverflow does it).

The form is at /posts/new (or /posts/xxx/edit).

Current problems:

- Once this page is loaded, the message works but then also shows when trying to leave any page. How can I restrict this to only this page?
- The alert is triggered via turbo, but it's not the same "Leave Site?" browser pop-up

I want it to look like this for both the window event and turbo event:
[image: Leave Site? Pop-up]

This is how it currently looks when trigger via Turbo:
[image: Leave Site? Pop-up via Turbo]

Here is my current JS code:

```
// javascript/controllers/unsaved_changes_controller.js
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"

const alert_message = "Leave site? Changes you made may not be saved."

export default class extends Controller {

  connect() {
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", (event) => {
      leavingPage(event);
    });  
    document.addEventListener('turbo:before-visit', (event) => {
      leavingPage(event);
    });
  }
  
}

function leavingPage(event) {
  console.log("leavingPage")
  if (event.type == "turbo:before-visit") {
    if (!window.confirm(alert_message)) { 
      event.preventDefault()
    }
  } else {
    event.returnValue = alert_message;
    return event.returnValue;
  }
}
```

And my view:

```
<form ... data-controller="unsaved-changes">
```

Answer (score 1):

### How can I restrict this to only this page?

- The simplest way to do this would be just to not add the `data-controller="unsaved-changes"` when you do not want to trigger the warning.
- Alternatively you can read the event's `detail.url` to check what URL is being navigated to https://turbo.hotwired.dev/reference/events OR read the current URL via `window.location`.

### Use the same "Leave Site?" browser pop-up

This special alert / pop-up cannot be triggered in any other way except for the actual `beforeunload` event usage.

Even using this has some caveats and scenarios where it will not work - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#usage_notes